# Can I assume that a biologist will know what "lhs" and "rhs" mean? Or what are some other ways of indicating the left/right hand sides of an equation?

Tags: notation

I am writing a scientific article with a few mathematical equations. Can I assume that my audience will know what lhs and rhs mean?

Comment: This question is not about mathematics at all.

Comment: @Adrian two commenters at english.stackexchange.com suggested that I ask the question here within a few minutes of asking... although I have usually had good experience asking technical questions on that site

Comment: Well David, the fact that they suggested you to ask it in here does not imply that it is appropriate for this site.

Comment: @adrian, fair enough. I just wanted to point out that I had already tried what I also thought was a more appropriate site.

Comment: Agree with Adrián. Voted to close as off-topic.

Comment: This is relevant. It is about how mathematics is discussed. I agree with PEV's comment it should be LHS and RHS. But the first time you use it, just mention left hand side(LHS).

Comment: The answer to the question as stated depends on your audience. I agree that this is not a mathematical question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you even have to think if your audience knows what a particular abbreviation means, then you *must* explain it.

In any case, writing LHS/RHS in anything but very informal contexts seems simply unacceptable to me.

Answer (score 3):

I like to define acronyms like:

"The left hand side (LHS) of Equation 1..."

And then use LHS throughout the rest of the paper if it is used frequently. If you only use "left hand side" a few times, it's best to just spell it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think abbreviations like that rarely pay.

Comment: Agreed. I would never use those abbreviations without explanation even when writing for mathematicians!

Comment: Ironic answer from someone with your name!

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be pretty obvious. Or you can simply say that LHS means "left hand side" and RHS means "right hand side." But many biologists have probably studied some probability or statistics. So they might have seen this notation before.

Comment: good point; is more proper to use capitalization?

Comment: @David: I think it is proper to use capitalization.